# Homological description of the degree of a map to $\mathbb P^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, riemann-surfaces

Let $f \colon X \to \mathbb P^n$, $n \geq 2$, be a holomorphic map from a compact Riemann surface $X$ and whose image $f(X)$ is a smooth projective curve. There are two notions of degree for such a map $f$:

1. the degree $d_1$ as the degree of the map of Riemann surfaces $\widetilde f: X \to f(X)$ which is the number of sheets of the ramified covering;
2. the degree $d_2$ of any divisor in the associated linear system $|f|$, or the degree of the hyperplane divisor $f^*(H)$.

We know that these notions of degree are different and are related: $d_2 = d_1 \cdot \deg f(X)$.

Passing to homology, we see that $f$ induces the following maps:

1. $\widetilde f_* \colon H_2(X) \to H_2(f(X))$. Since both groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, this is given by $\widetilde f_*[1] = k[1]$ and one can show that $k=d_1$ (up to a sign).
2. $f_* \colon H_2(X) \to H_2(\mathbb P^n)$. Both groups are again isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, so this map is $f_*[1] = m[1]$ for some $m$. Is it true that $m = d_2$ (up to a sign)?

Due to the formula relating $d_1$ to $d_2$, we can reformulate the above question in the following form. We have $f = i \circ \widetilde f$, where $i\colon f(X) \hookrightarrow \mathbb P^n$. This map descends to $f_* = i_* \circ \widetilde f_*$, where $i_* \colon H_2(f(X)) \to H_2(\mathbb P^n)$. Since the latter spaces are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, we have $i_*[1] = l[1]$. Thus, having $m=d_2$ is equivalent to having $l = \deg f(X)$. Thus, the equivalent question is whether $\deg f(X) = l$ (up to a sign)?

Comment: Yes, it is true that $l=\operatorname{deg} f(X)$. There are a couple of ways to see this: for example by Poincare duality, or the fact that a curve of degree $d$ can be deformed into a union of $d$ lines. Another comment is that in algebraic (or complex) geometry, there are no signs! Subvarieties have a canonical orientation, hence homology class, and homology classes of subvarieties of $\mathbf P^n$ of the same dimension are always _positive_ multiples of each other.